# How to calculate number of mantissa bits?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, precision, mantissa

I want to calculate number of mantissa bits in float and double.
I know those numbers should be 23 and 52, but I have to calculate it in my program.

Comment: Why do you need to calculate it  in your program?

Comment: Maybe you can start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: @EdHeal at a rough guess, because that's what the OP's prof/TA asked for.

Comment: Calculate it how..? By twiddling a float around and seeing how it changes? There are constants for these values in headers, if you don't want to hardcode magic numbers.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen yeah, float-twiddling and bit-checking was all I could think of, if forced to find out in software what I could just look up in documentation..

Comment: For a more "C++" answer, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57201197/193789)

Answer (score 5):

There are constants you can use defined in the header [`<cfloat>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cfloat)

See FLT_MANT_DIG for example.

Comment: Just remember to take FLT_RADIX into account, in case you might be running on a computer that doesn't use base-2 floats!

Answer (score 3):

There is an ambiguity in *number of mantissa bits*: it could be

- the number of bits needed to represent the floating point value.
- the number of bits stored into the floating point representation.

Typically, the mantissa as stored in the IEEE floating point format does not include the initial `1` that is implied for all regular non zero numbers. Therefore the number of bits in the representation is one less that the true number of bits.

You can compute this number for the binary floating point formats in different ways:

- some systems define manifest contants `FLT_MANT_BITS`, `DBL_MANT_BITS` and `LDBL_MANT_BITS`. The value is the true number of mantissa bits.
- you can derive the number of bits from a direct computation involving `FLT_EPSILON` defined in `<float.h>`:  `FLT_EPSILON` is the smallest float value such that `1.0f + FLT_EPSILON` is different from `1.0f`.  The true number of  mantissa is `1 - log(FLT_EPSILON) / log(2)`.  The same formula can be used for other floating point formats.
- you can compute the values with a loop, as illustrated in the code below.

Here is a test utility:

```
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int n;
    float f = 1.0;
    for (n = 0; 1.0f + f != 1.0f; n++) {
        f /= 2;
    }
#ifdef FLT_MANT_BITS
    printf("#define FLT_MANT_BITS       %d\n", FLT_MANT_BITS);
#endif
#ifdef FLT_EPSILON
    printf("1 - log(FLT_EPSILON)/log(2) =  %g\n", 1 - log(FLT_EPSILON) / log(2));
#endif
    printf("Mantissa bits for float: %d\n", n);
    double d = 1.0;
    for (n = 0; 1.0 + d != 1.0; n++) {
        d /= 2;
    }
#ifdef DBL_MANT_BITS
    printf("#define DBL_MANT_BITS       %d\n", DBL_MANT_BITS);
#endif
#ifdef DBL_EPSILON
    printf("1 - log(DBL_EPSILON)/log(2) =  %g\n", 1 - log(DBL_EPSILON) / log(2));
#endif
    printf("Mantissa bits for double: %d\n", n);
    long double ld = 1.0;
    for (n = 0; 1.0 + ld != 1.0; n++) {
        ld /= 2;
    }
#ifdef LDBL_MANT_BITS
    printf("#define LDBL_MANT_BITS      %d\n", LDBL_MANT_BITS);
#endif
#ifdef LDBL_EPSILON
    printf("1 - log(LDBL_EPSILON)/log(2) = %g\n", 1 - log(LDBL_EPSILON) / log(2));
#endif
    printf("Mantissa bits for long double: %d\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Output on my laptop:

```
1 - log(FLT_EPSILON)/log(2) =  24
Mantissa bits for float:       24
1 - log(DBL_EPSILON)/log(2) =  53
Mantissa bits for double:      53
1 - log(LDBL_EPSILON)/log(2) = 64
Mantissa bits for long double: 64
```

Comment: "number of mantissa bits" , though not _precisely_ defined, should be +1 or `53` for double.  The count should reflect the mathematics of the value which has a 53 bit significand even though with typical FP formats, only 52 are explicitly stored (1 implied).  (C++, certain `DBL_MANT_DIG` --> 53

Comment: I agree, this notion is a bit confusing, a more thorough explanation was needed.  I came up with a simpler computation too.